# Error connection refused while registering user in django registration

Tags: django

I followed this post [How to disable email activation in django-registration app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838710/how-to-disable-email-activation-in-django-registration-app) and made changes to my django-registration code . So even though user is getting registered once I click on submit button , it still gives me an error page saying socket error . That means it is still trying to send the mail , though I have set it to false . How to get rid of this ?

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing this is in development? rather then turning email off you could try setting the email backend to [dummy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#dummy-backend) or [file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#file-backend) in your `settings.py` while in debug.

```
if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
```