# django registration disable activation email not working

Tags: django, django-cms, django-registration

I was trying to disable sending  email activation of activation. but it is not happening

What i tried is i copy the registration folder in to my project  and by following [How to disable email activation in django-registration app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838710/how-to-disable-email-activation-in-django-registration-app) answers i changed in the file but it is not happening .

i also done the same changes in the files of the folder 
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration/
but still it is not stopping .

When i do register it is going the page that verification email is send and when i check in admin it is showing not activated .

Please suggest what can be problem

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hacking, use [SimpleBackend](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/registration/backends/simple/__init__.py) which doesn't send anything but registers user immediately.